# Почему может быть предпочтительнее возведение в квадрат, вместо извлечения квадратного корня?

Tags: pascal, оптимизация, математика

Есть два способа нахождения простых чисел:

```
var n,m,p,i,k:longint;
    f:boolean;
begin
  read(n);
  read(m);
  k:=0;
  for p:=n to m do
  begin
    f:=true;
    i:=2;
    while (i*i<=p) and f do
      if p mod i=0 then 
        f:=false
      else 
        i:=i+1;
    if f then
    begin
      writeln(p);
      k:=1;
    end;
  end;
  if k=0 then 
    writeln('Absent');
end.
```

и

```
var n,m,p,i,k:longint;
    f:boolean;
begin
  read(n);
  read(m);
  k:=0;
  for p:=n to m do
  begin
    f:=true;
    i:=2;
    while (i<=sqrt(p)) and f do
      if p mod i=0 then 
        f:=false
      else 
        i:=i+1;
    if f then
    begin
      writeln(p);
      k:=1;
    end;
  end;
  if k=0 then 
    writeln('Absent');
end.
```

Объясните пожалуйста что значит условие **(i*i<=p)** в первой реализации? 
Я понимаю, что работает быстрее, хочу понять почему.

Comment: простите, для вас не очевидно что `a*a <b` и `a < sqrt(b)` эквивалентны? И работают при нормальной компиляции они одинаково (в пределах погрешности).

Comment: Pavel, тогда вопрос в лоб, препод просит объяснить, почему при поиске чисел в диапазоне(от 300 000 - 1 000 000), первая реализация более оптимальная?

Comment: запустите и проверьте. Запускайте на fpc в -O2 хотя бы. Разницу визуально не заметите...

Comment: Я думаю, что препод хочет получить следующий ответ. "Потому что операция умножения `*` выполняется быстрее, чем взятие квадратного корня `sqrt`. Умножение может быть выполнено одной командой процессора, а квадратный корень - это сложная и длительная итерационная операция." Но вообще-то, похоже что препод просто не в курсе, что современный математический сопроцессор способен вычислять квадратный корень с той же скоростью, что и умножать.

Comment: @kff и нормальный компилятор вынесет вычисление ДО цикла, поэтому операция будет выполнена |len| операций, а сам цикл порядка |len sqrt M| и на этом фоне уже всё равно как считать... И да, полностью согласен, корень можно вычислить за 2-3 операции умножения.

Comment: дело было действительно в скорости вычисления умножения и корня.

Comment: Вы ему еще намекните, что еще оптимальнее отдельно проверить делимость на 2, а в цикле проверять, начиная с `i:=3;`, и написать `else i:=i+2;`...

Comment: @kff квадратный корень невозможно вычислить с той же скоростью что и умножение. Замедление будет в любом случае.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что препод хочет получить следующий ответ:

> "Потому что операция умножения * выполняется быстрее, чем взятие квадратного корня sqrt. Умножение может быть выполнено одной командой процессора, а квадратный корень - это сложная и длительная итерационная операция."

Но вообще-то, похоже что препод просто не в курсе, что современный математический сопроцессор способен вычислять квадратный корень с той же скоростью, что и умножать.
*– kff*

---

@kff и нормальный компилятор вынесет вычисление ДО цикла, поэтому операция будет выполнена |len| операций, а сам цикл порядка |len sqrt M| и на этом фоне уже всё равно как считать... И да, полностью согласен, корень можно вычислить за 2-3 операции умножения.
*- pavel*

---

От себя замечу, что, по крайней мере, при работе с числами с точкой, в циклах, умножение все же быстрее, чем извлечение корня.

Comment: "современный математический сопроцессор способен вычислять квадратный корень с той же скоростью, что и умножать" - эм.. но умножение-то целочисленное, а взятие корня - нет.

Answer (score 0):

По идее, целочисленное умножение быстрее операций над дробными числами - в данном случае извлечения корня. Но это не единственная причина. Тем более вычисление корня можно вынести перед циклом, т. к. в цикле p не меняется. И получится одна операция вместо кучи умножений в цикле.

Не знаю Паскаль, но предположу, что для чисел используется 64-битный целый тип.
Когда мы извлекаем квадратный корень, то число приводится в вещественному двойной точности. Там 53 значащих бита, а не 64. Упс. В этом потенциальный баг второго алгоритма. Хотя при целочисленном умножении мы должны бы позаботить об отсутствии переполнения.

На значениях (2<sup>27</sup>+1)<sup>2</sup> = 18014398777917441 и (2<sup>30</sup>+1)<sup>2</sup> = 1152921506754330625 баг не проявляется. Честно говоря не уверен, можно ли подобрать число, являющееся полным квадратом, так чтобы квадратный корень из него, приведённого к double, получился строго меньше оригинального. Но если удастся, то это будет означать, что второй алгоритм содержит ошибку. Поэтому там обычно ещё что-нибудь добавляют, чтобы точно захватить корень.

Да, что касается самого алгоритма - там куча мест, которые можно оптимизировать. Если мы уже определили, что число не простое, проверять дальнейшие его делители нецелесообразно. Единственное чётное простое - это 2, все остальные чётные можно не проверять. Как и не проверять чётные делители.

А ещё можно реализовать алгоритм на основе решета Эратосфена. На основе, потому что тут задан промежуток, не начинающийся в 1.